# Twig for print key

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, loops, twig

I have this kind of array (print_r):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Alsace] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idd] => 67
                    [departement] => Bas-Rhin
                    [region] => 7
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idd] => 68
                    [departement] => Haut-Rhin
                    [region] => 7
                )

        )

    [Aquitaine] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idd] => 24
                    [departement] => Dordogne
                    [region] => 12
                )
        )
)
```

In PHP, it is as simple as that to browse into:

```
foreach($json_data as $key => $v) {
    echo '<optgroup label="'.$key.'">';
        foreach ($v as $key => $value) {
            echo '<option value="'.$value["idd"].'" class="r_'.$value["region"].'">'.$value["idd"].' – '.$value["departement"].'</option>';
        }
    echo '</optgroup>';
}
```

But in twig, I try

```
{% for key, region in json_data %}
    <optgroup label="{{ key }}">
        {% for dep in region %}
            <option value="{{ dep.idd }}" class="r_{{ dep.region }}">{{ dep.idd }} – {{ dep.departement }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </optgroup>
{% endfor %}
```

But it seems I'm browsing into nothing... According to the doc, it should be the way to do it..

Comment: I believe Twig expects a php array and it looks like you are passing an object. Is it really json_data?

Comment: Indeed @nerdlyist, I passed on object to twig. I add a true parameter to json_decode to convert into array. Thanks

Comment: @Macbernie you have me confused now did you solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, the `for` can't loop object properties by default. Only was is casting it to an array, which you seem to have done